# Organizing code in C# projects

Tags: c#, project-organization

I have an interface:

```
public interface IMyObject
{
}
```

I have an abstract class:

```
public abstract class MyObject : IMyObject
{
}
```

And I have a class:

```
public class MyExtendedObject : MyObject
{
}
```

There are many interfaces, abstracts and concretes like this in my project. I wonder what is the best scenario to organize the code in namespace (folders in project) point of view. Should I put all related stuff under the same folder or should create, for example a Base namespace for abstract classes, Interfaces namespace for interfaces and another namespace for extended objects?

Comment: The "best" way is the one you agree upon with your team-mates

Comment: I develop the project by myself, there are no teammates. But I also consider to host my library in CodePlex as an open-source, because I think it's worth to share with the people of Earth for good.

Answer (score 5):

The *best* way is subjective and poject dependent.

Like a suggession I would say:

move in separate folder interfaces and abstract classes, so separate them from *concrete* implementation classes.

```
+ Absrtacts 
     -> IMyObject.cs 
     -> MyObject.cs 

+ Concrete 
     -> MyExtendedObject.cs
```

Answer (score 4):

Robert C. Martin (one of the founding fathers of Agile and now the Software Craftmanship movement) has a whole talk on that that is [**really worth watching**](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WpkDN78P884)

It's based on Ivar Jacobson's [Object Oriented Software Engineering: A Use Case Driven Approach](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201544350).

To summarize it in a few sentences, your project structure should reflect what it models and not the technology or particular language constructs you use. In the case of your abstract/interface/concrete classes this means that using a structure where you put all your abstract classes in a folder/namspace/assembly, your concrete classes in another folder/namespace/assembly is not the way to go (even though it is very common to find projects where this approach is taken).

Comment: Funny guy, good educational video. Really worth to watch. But I guess there is no common sense on this subject, 'cause your way of thinking differs than @Tigran. I'd like to see more comments to arrive a decision, thank you.